# I am using stripe for the first time and the documentations are not clear about subscriptions?

Tags: django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

Does stripe work like this? I am expecting that stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve return a JSON like the following.

#### **GOAL**

1. I want to check if the user has a subscription or free trial.
2. I also need to check if the last payment had an error like card does not have enough balance or if the subscription is expired.
3. also does stripe automatically pay or should I schedule celery_beat cron tasks that pay every 30 days?

```py
    @property
    def is_valid_subscribion(self):
        try:
            customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_id)

            payment = stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_id)
        except Exception as e:
            return False, "You don't have a subscription."

        if payment["last_payment_error"] is not None: return False, "Your subscription is expired please make sure your card is valid"

        # subscription = stripe.Subscription.retrieve(customer=customer)
```

Comment: You can achieve goal 1 and 2 using Subscriptions API, specifically list subscriptions where you can list subscriptions by Customer ID [1] as well as check its status to verify if the last payment failed (i.e. it would be `past_due`)

And yes if the subscription collection_method is set to `charge_automatically` then you don't need to schedule a cron task. Stripe will collect the payment automatically [2].


[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list?lang=python 
[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=python#create_subscription-collection_method

Comment: @hanzo how can i do that in code? can you add anser?

Comment: @hanzo
so i can do it like this
if `stripe.Subscription.retrieve(customer=customer)['status']=="active"` then the user has a valid subscription `else` the Subscription is expired or failed to pay

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: what error are you seeing? are you sure you're using the right syntax? 
`stripe.Subscription.retreive(customer=customer,status='active')` I think.